# Density estimation with Orthogonal series

Tags: statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-series, density-function, mean-square-error

I have found this problem from the article http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/watson-density.pdf. In this article the probability density function has considered as
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{m}\phi_{m}(x),
\end{equation}
and the estimator is
\begin{equation}
 f^{\ast}_{n}(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \lambda_{m}a_{m}\phi_{m}(x),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
   a_{m} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi_{m}(x_k).
\end{equation}
Here $\{\phi_{m}(x)\}$ is an orthonormal basis. According to the article
\begin{equation}
  E \int (f(x)-f^{\ast}(x))^2dx= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}E(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})^2=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\{\alpha_{m}^2(1-\lambda_{m})^2+\frac{1}{n}\lambda^2_{m}\text{var}(\phi_{m}(x))\}.
\end{equation}
I have been trying to prove this. My approach is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 E\int (f(x)-f^{\ast}(x))^2dx & = \int E(f(x)-f^{\ast}(x))^2dx\; [by Fubini]\\
& = \int E\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})\phi_{m}(x)\right]^2dx\\
& = \int E\left(\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})^2\phi_{m}(x)^2\right]+2 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})(\alpha_{j}-\lambda_{j}a_{j})\phi_{m}(x)\phi_{j}(x)\right)dx\\
& = E\left(\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})^2\int\phi_{m}(x)^2dx\right]+2 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})(\alpha_{j}-\lambda_{j}a_{j})\int\phi_{m}(x)\phi_{j}(x)dx\right)\\
& = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}E(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Note that $\alpha_{m}=E\phi_{m}(x)$.
Now,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E(\alpha_m-\lambda_m a_m)^2 & = E(\alpha_m-\alpha_m \lambda_m+\alpha_m \lambda_m+\lambda_m a_m)^2\\
& = E[\alpha_{m}(1-\lambda_m)+\lambda_m(\alpha_m-a_m)]^2\\
& = E[\alpha_{m}^2(1-\lambda_m)^2+2\alpha_{m}(1-\lambda_m)\lambda_m(\alpha_m-a_m)+\lambda_m^2(\alpha_m-a_m)^2]\\
& = \alpha_{m}^2(1-\lambda_m)^2+ 2\alpha_{m}(1-\lambda_m)\lambda_mE(\alpha_m-a_m)+\lambda_m^2E(\alpha_m-a_m)^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 E(\alpha_{m}-a_{m}) & = \alpha_{m}-Ea_{m}\\
& = \alpha_{m}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\phi_{m}(x_k)\\
& = \alpha_{m}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{m}\\
& = \alpha_{m}-\alpha_{m}=0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E(\alpha_{m}-\lambda_{m}a_{m})^2=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_{m}^2(1-\lambda_{m})^2+\lambda_{m}^2E(\alpha_{m}-a_{m})^2.
\end{equation}

I was wondering is there any way to prove
\begin{equation}
  E(\alpha_{m}-a_{m})^2=\frac{1}{n}\text{var}(\phi_{m}(x)).
\end{equation}

Comment: The same [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-40/issue-4/Density-Estimation-by-Orthogonal-Series/10.1214/aoms/1177697523.full) on a more secure site.

Comment: DOI link, please

Comment: I have attached link of the article @ 
Rodrigo de Azevedo